# How to switch Site Search Results to 2010 theme results page ( with its extras ) from a 2007 theme search page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

We have parts of a site using a 2007 theme and a few that use 2010.
Despite using search on either theme, the results default to a 2007 theme results page without the 2010 search rrsults left side bar.
How do I change this across the board please?